# How do I install MS Web Deploy to an Azure Windows Server 2012 R2 VM in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, azure, iis, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to script creation of a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM using PowerShell.  The VM is to run IIS and I want to deploy ASP .Net web sites to the IIS on the VM using Web Deploy.

So far I have successfully created a Windows Server VM and configured IIS on.  The part I am having trouble with is how to script deployment of Web Deploy to the VM.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Install the vm extension check the devpart at the end of this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn606311.aspx

Comment: This doesn't sound like it would be useful for production... it is under the heading of Development and Debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a code snippet I use. I launch the custom script extension via arm template to fire off a powershell script

```
  if (!(test-path c:\temp))
    {
    mkdir c:\temp\
    }
    #web deploy v3.6
    $webdeployURL = 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/D/01DC28EA-638C-4A22-A57B-4CEF97755C6C/WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi'
    $webdeployOutFileMSI = 'c:\temp\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi'
    wget -uri $webdeployURL -OutFile $webdeployOutFileMSI

    $list = 
    @(
        "/I `"$webdeployOutFileMSI`"",                     
        "/passive",                            
        "ADDLOCAL=ALL LISTENURL=http://+:8080/MSWEBDEPLOY/",
        "/L*V `"c:\temp\wdlog.log`""    
    )

    if ((get-windowsfeature Web-Mgmt-Service).InstallState -eq 'Installed')
    {
    Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec" -ArgumentList $list -Wait
    }
    else
    {
    Add-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service 
    Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec" -ArgumentList $list -Wait
    }

    Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server -Name EnableRemoteManagement -Value 1
    Restart-Service wmsvc

    if ((get-service -Name 'msdepsvc').Status -ne 'Running')
    {
    net start msdepsvc
    }

    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allow Web Management (WMSVC)" dir=in action=allow service="WMSVC"
```

Comment: Close the string it's all red